# What amendments were made to the Outer Space Treaty?

Tags: law

[Article XV](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty_of_1967#Article_XV) of the [Outer Space Treaty](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty_of_1967) (henceforth OuST) is a provision for amendments to the original treaty.

The treaty dates back almost half-a-century (46 years to be a little more precise).

Since that date, what amendments, if any, were proposed, voted upon, and passed? Is the OuST mostly dormant despite significant changes globally on both the technological, and political fronts?

Comment: @Everyone You can browse [these google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=proposed+amendment+to+outer+space+treaty&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=) to see how common proposed amendments are, but none have ever moved past the proposal stage.

Answer (score 12):

According to Andrew Tingkang of Seattle University School of Law (in a paper from 2011), the Outer Space Treaty has never been amended. The amendment addressed in "Common Ground in the Sky: Extending the 1967 Outer Space Treaty to Reconcile U.S. and Chinese Security Interests" by Alex B. Engelhart was a proposed amendment that was never ratified.

**Sources:**

- [These Aren’t the Asteroids You Are Looking For: Classifying Asteroids in Space as Chattels, Not Land - Andrew Tingkang, Seattle University School of Law](http://digitalcommons.law.seattleu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2070&context=sulr)
- [Common Ground in the Sky: Extending the 1967 Outer Space Treaty to Reconcile U.S. and Chinese Security Interests - Alex B. Engelhart, University of Washington School of Law](http://digital.law.washington.edu/dspace-law/bitstream/handle/1773.1/568/17PacRimLPolyJ133.pdf?sequence=1)